# Making value type variables nullable by using "?": does it imply boxing?

Tags: c#, nullable, value-type, boxing, nullable-reference-types

Given the following assumptions in C#:

1. boxing and unboxing let me convert any value type variable to an object type, which is a reference type (therefore it's also nullable), like in the example:

> ```
> int i = 123;
> object box = i;
> ```

2. The "?" operator let me convert a not-nullable integer into a nullable variable, like in the example:

> `int? n = 0;`

My Question: for only reference type variables are nullable, can I say that in the second example I'm doing implicit boxing? In other terms, when I use the "**?**" operator **to make nullable an integer**, is there **boxing** operation implied as well (even if it's not explicit)?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1#boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: No it doesnt, it is the same procedure as creating ordinary struct with a field. no boxing for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int?` is suggar for `Nullable<T>` [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netcore-3.1). If we look at the signature of this we see:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
...
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
      if (!this.hasValue)
        return other == null;
      return other != null && this.value.Equals(other);
    }
```

Since it is a struct the value will not be boxed.

If you need to compare values, `n.Equals(1)` would cause boxing of the argument. I cannot find any documentation about the equality operator `==`, but I think it would be fairly safe to assume that it should not cause boxing.

Comment: thank you for your answer. For 'struct Nullable<T>' is a value type may I assume that it's stored in the stack like the standard not-nullable int variables, whereas a boxed integer is stored in the heap memory?

Comment: @franz it depends on context. If it is a parameter or local variable it would on the stack. If it is part of an object it could be stored on the heap. But this is non-contractual. The CLR is allowed to store objects wherever it pleases, as long as it follows the rules of the language.